# Remove exactly one line in a file

Tags: command-line

I have a file that contains the following lines:

```
SUKsoft:
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_Comment
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_R
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_RW
```

How can I remove the line "SUKsoft:"?

This line could be in any place of the file (beginning as it is now, or in the middle).

Is there a command to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` searches for lines that satisfy a pattern.  `grep -v` *discards* lines that satisfy a pattern.

```
grep -v '^SUKsoft: *$'
```

The pattern is: lines that start (`^`) with `SUKsoft:`, possibly followed by spaces but nothing else until the end of the line (`$`).

Answer (score 8):

To **remove** the line use

```
sed -i '/SUKsoft:\s*$/d' your_file
```

Example

```
% cat foo
SUKsoft: 
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_Comment   
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_R
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_RW

% sed -i '/SUKsoft:\s*$/d' foo

% cat foo                    
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_Comment   
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_R
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_RW
```

Comment: You are actually doing it the other way around as matching all lines having **SUKsoft:[space][any stuff after that]** **@souravc** answer is much closer to the op question

Comment: Any stuff after that? What do you mean? `\s*$` means, many whitespaces as possible and a line end. There is no `any stuff`

Comment: Oh never mind, misread that

Comment: Note that \s would need -E on most other platforms and may even be unsupported altogether. Since this is Ubuntu specific site it's fine. [[:space:]] for Posix.

Comment: @Melvyn thank you for the note. I will add this.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps to remove the desired line:

```
$ sed 's/SUKsoft: *$//' file.txt

SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_Comment
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_R
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_RW
```

I am assuming `file.txt` contains the lines.

Or,

```
$ sed 's/SUKsoft: *$//; /^$/d' file.txt
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_Comment
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_R
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_RW
```

it does not leave any **blank** line.

To edit in the file you can use,

```
sed -i 's/SUKsoft: *$//' file.txt
```

or

```
sed -i 's/SUKsoft: *$//; /^$/d' file.txt
```

as per your need.

See [A.B](https://askubuntu.com/a/691517/127327)'s answer where it is done in more compact manner. Thanks to [Wildcard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691512/remove-exactly-line-in-a-file/691514#comment1009744_691514).

Comment: Note that there is a space after the `:` in the OP's text.  The space would need to be included in the regex for this to work.  I would recommend inserting ` *` (space asterisk) after the colon and before the `$` in the regex, so that any number of spaces (including 0) would be matched.  Also, just to be sure you don't match unexpected lines, it might be good to prepend a `^`.

Comment: Also, I only realized it when I read A.B.'s answer, but (1) the `g` flag isn't doing anything here (since there can only be a match at the end of the line anyways) and (2) this will leave blank lines in the file as opposed to removing the lines completely.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your [post't raw source](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/34229438-839c-47bd-93be-ae89381adca2/view-source) there's no space or sequence of spaces after "SUKsoft:", however just to be on the safe side this command will take care of those if present.

Using Perl:

```
perl -ne '!/^SUKsoft: *$/&&print' input
```

- `!/^SUKsoft:$/&&print`: if the current line doesn't match the pattern `^SUKsoft: *$`, which matches a line starting with `SUKsoft:` string followed by zero or more spaces, prints the line;

```
% cat input
SUKsoft:
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_Comment
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_R
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_RW
% perl -ne 'print unless /^SUKsoft: *$/' input
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_Comment
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_R
SUKsoft: App-Conduct_Risk_RW
```